# Как и где правильно хранить секретные данные в ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rsa

У меня усть Web API, где используется RSA для шифрования некоторых данных. Подскажите, как грамотно передать ключ в API, что бы это было надёжно и секьюрно? В текущей реализации, ключ передаётся, в виде файлика **.pem** а путь к нему, указывается в конфиг файле.

Мне кажется что этот подход крайне не верен с точки зрения реализации, хотелось бы узнать best practices, как решаются подобные задачи?

Comment: А зачем такая муть, чем не угодило обычное хранилище секретов asp.net ? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows

Comment: @air2921 недостаток опыта работы с криптограцией сказывается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще часто такие данные хранятся в **Хранилище секретов ASP.NET Core**, а не в отдельных файлах.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=windows

Если лень читать доку, то вот так это делается:

Открываем cmd там указываем папку с Web API проектом, в этой папке должен находится файл **.csproj**
Примерно вот так это выглядит:

```
cd C:\Users\User\source\repos\Проект\webapi
```

Далее вводим команду для инициализации хранилища:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
```

После этого вы можете сохранять ваши секреты в этом хранилище:

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Ключ" "Значение секрета"
```

После инициализации хранилища, и добавления секретов, настраиваете свой **IСonfiguration** на работу с хранилищем секретов:

```
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddUserSecrets<Тут обычно Program/Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Теперь в контроллере, или любом другом месте вашего приложения где нужен ключ, получаем его:

Инициализуем нужные поля:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
private readonly string secretKey;
```

Теперь в конструкторе класса:

```
public ВашКласс(IСonfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    secretKey = _configuration["Ключ под которым сохранен ваш секрет"];
}
```

Если ключ представляет из себя массив байтов закодированный в Base64String (Что очень даже распространенно для ключей шифрования), то можно немного модифицировать получение ключа:

Также инициализуем поле для ключа, только уже типа byte[]:

```
private readonly byte[] secretKey;
```

И в конструкторе класса, при получении добавим метод для конвертации значения в массив байтов:

```
public ВашКласс(IСonfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    secretKey = Convert.FromBase64String(_configuration["Ключ под которым сохранен ваш секрет"]);
}
```

Теперь этот ключ можно использовать в любом месте класса где он "инжектирован"

```
public IActionResult GetKey()
{
    return StatusCode(200, new { secretKey });
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, попробую Ваш вариант.

Comment: Только `user-secrets` - это для разработки, а не для сервера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А где-то было указано что нужен вариант именно для прода ? Я думаю люди которые уже хостят сайт понимают что такие данные хранятся уже в **AWS SM** / **Azure KV**